# Bootstrap modal doesn't open on some devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm tring to open Bootstrap modal by clicking a button. I't works from my browser and from some galaxy devices, but it's not working from Iphone and from my Galaxy A70. (my friend also tried it from A70 and it works fine!!!)

I realy dont know what is going on because it works before and now I just changed the modal content.

In addition, when I write an alert inside this function-$("#exampleModalCenter").on("show.bs.modal") on my JS code, the alert is shown in my device.

If someone can help me I would be realy thankful!

my HTML code for triggering the modal:

```
<button type="button" style="font-size: medium ;" class="btn btn-outline-primary  btn-sm btn-block container-non-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-title="T-shirt" data-tag="3">
    <b>choose</b>          
    </button>
     </p>
```

my modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                <div class="modal-header " dir="rtl">
                    <h5 class="modal-title " id="exampleModalCenterTitle" dir="rtl"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 65px;">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 ">
                            <table class="table table-borderless table-sm">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group dropdown " dir="rtl">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropDownQuantity" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                      </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu quantites" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="dropdown ">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropDownSize" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" dir="rtl">

                      </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu sizes" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                        <div class="dropdown ">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropDownColor" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" dir="rtl">

                    </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu color" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" id="colorDiv">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="americanTr">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>

                                        <div class="dropdown " id="americanChoseSleeveDD">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropDownSleeveColor" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" dir="rtl">

                    </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu Sleevecolor" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" id="sleeveColorDiv">


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="table table-borderless table-sm">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group dropdown " dir="rtl">
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary  dropdown-toggle " type="button" id="dropDownSchool" style="margin-left: 40px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-lg-left school" id="schoolDiv" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group dropdown " dir="rtl">
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary  dropdown-toggle " type="button" id="dropDownLocation" style="margin-right: 10px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-lg-left location" id="cityDiv" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3" dir="rtl" id="schoolNameElseDiv">
                                <label for="schoolName" style="float: right;">else</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="schoolName" id="schoolNameElseInput" placeholder="add your school name" value="" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback d-block" style="text-align: right;">
                                    required
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-borderless table-sm" id="symbols" style="max-width: 100%;">
                    <tr id=symbolsPlace>

                    </tr>

                </table>
                <p class="mb-1 text-muted text-center text-small">
                    <a href=" #0" onclick="openSizeRuler()">open size ruler</a> </p>
                <div class="modal-footer" dir="rtl">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col text-center">
                                <span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="required">
                    <button  type="button"  disabled onclick="addToCartClick()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary " id="addToCart"  style="pointer-events: none;">  add &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i></button>            
                  </span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**OpenSizeRuler function opens another modal inside.**

I hope you guies can help me.

**UPDATE:**

I found the problem but I dont know how to face it:

Inside the modal I have a dropdown which it's values are taken from another class. When I create an instance of the class inside the function that generate the dropdown- the modal stop working and not showes up.

the way I use the class:

```
function generateCityDD() {
    var citiy = new Schools();
    var cityArr = citiy.getCitiesArr();
    appendToDropDown(cityArr, "cityDiv");
    $(".location button").click(function() {
        $("#dropDownLocation").text($(this).text());
        selectLocation = $(this).text();
        $("#dropDownSchool").text("choose a school");
        selectSchool = null;
        validate();
        generateSchoolsDD();

    });

}
```

any ideas?

Comment: post work snippet for test it please.

Comment: @Simone Rossaini I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours I figured it out-
I had a problem with the class constructor :)